# JS: loop through array of URL's and alert if any throw an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I have an associative array of URL's, each with a unique identifier that i want to iterate through and whichever URL throws a 401 i'd like to set an alert of that specific url's identifier. I'm stuck at the alerting portion:

```
   for (var i=0; i<lyrs.length; i++){
        $.ajax({
            url: lyrs[i],
            dataType: 'json',
            statusCode: {
                401: function(){
                    console.log('there was a 401 error on something');
                }
            }
        });            
    }
```

Comment: What exactly seems to be the issue?

Comment: Seeing the ajax calls are asynchronous you will have most likely moved on to the next indexed url by the time any of the previous ones throw the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the function that you associate with `401` can take the same arguments that the `error` callback. Thus, you can write:

```
. . .
statusCode: {
    401: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // alert with the specific details
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I will read deeper into the docs and try to setup this argument

Comment: @atlMapper - If you want to alert any error, you might consider using a general error callback rather than status-code-specific callbacks.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I can use the "errorThrown" to show the specific error recieved from the function. Just to confirm. Since I'm iterating through the array,each errror shouldn't this show in the console If I create console.log inside the 401 section?

Comment: @atlMapper - Each url that generates a 401 error will generate a separate call to the callback function. The `errorThrown` argument will be the text portion of the HTTP response status header. However, if there's a different error response (404, etc.), then this callback won't be invoked. If you provide a general `error : function ...` in the object passed to `$.ajax()`, it will be invoked for any error response.

Answer (score 1):

Use a closure:

```
for (var i=0; i<lyrs.length; i++){
        (function() {
             var url=lyrs[i];
             $.ajax({
                 url: url,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 statusCode: {
                     401: function(){
                         console.log('there was a 401 error on '+url);
                     }
                 }
             });
        })();          
    }
```

Comment: I can't step into this, but its not firing off the console log...I'm going to look deeper into closure's thanks